# What exactly does the variable SERVER_PROTOCOL actually contain (Apache 2.4)?

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, https

I have a website served by Apache 2.4 which should serve all contents via HTTPS. I already have appropriate redirections in place which work correctly, but don't catch any pathological case. I wanted to improve that situation, and, when doing my homework, came across the following example in [this document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost):

```
<If "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} != 'HTTPS'">
    Redirect "/admin/" "https://www.example.com/admin/"
</If>
```

I slightly modified this to reflect my situation:

```
<If "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL} != 'HTTPS'">
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</If>
```

Now, when trying to view any URL from my site, the browser goes into an infinite redirection loop.

I am suspecting that the example actually is wrong. `SERVER_PROTOCOL` does not seem to contain the value `HTTPS` under any circumstances. Instead, according to what I have read in other articles, it contains things like `HTTP/1.1` (as the name would let expect).

So my question is: What exactly does `SERVER_PROTOCOL` contain under what circumstances / in what context? And what could be the reason that Apache's official documentation website is the only one I have found during several hours of research that lists `HTTPS` as a possible value of `SERVER_PROTOCOL`?

Comment: SERVER_PROTOCOL could be `HTTP/1.0` (old browsers), `HTTP/1.1` (most common nowadays), `HTTP/0.9` (when ommited by the client, pretty old software or manual tests) and probably `HTTP/2.0` at some point. It won't help you in your redirects for https. Also, if you are not going to use http under any circumstances, I would search for HSTS

Comment: Well, thank you very much and +1. Then the documentation is indeed wrong (I still can't believe that I'm the first one affected by that error). HSTS has been on my schedule anyway ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations, you found an error in the Apache documentation. Consider reporting it.

As for your immediate problem, you appear to be looking for `REQUEST_SCHEME`, [which will contain](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars)

> The scheme part of the request's URI

for instance, `http` or `https`.

Comment: Thanks - accepted as answer and +1. I'll try to find out how to file the bug. Regarding the actual problem: I already had found the page you linked, but didn't take it serious because I couldn't believe that there is such an error in the documentation. Furthermore, I already had tried using the `HTTPS` variable which had lead to another problem. The same problem arose when using `REQUEST_SCHEME` (this is a matter for a separate question)..